# Heroku reports "no app specified" on Windows command line

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a node.js application running on Heroku.  I've used the (Windows) command line to initialize the app with `heroku create`, and I can hit the production website and see that it's running correctly. All's good.

But when I try to run simple commands, like `heroku ps`, from the directory in which the app lives, Heroku responds with a "no app specified" error:

```
C:\dev\iq>heroku ps
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.
```

I've read in other posts that you can avoid having to use the `--app APP` syntax with every command if you configure git like so:

```
git config heroku.remote heroku
```

However, after doing so, Heroku still complains that the app wasn't specified for simple command line requests. I've verified that `.git/config` has been updated appropriately:

```
C:\dev\iq>type .git\config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.com:aqueous-mountain-xxxx.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[heroku]
    remote = heroku
```

I've just reinstalled the latest version of Heroku:

```
C:\dev\iq>heroku --version
heroku/toolbelt/3.2.2 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The 'heroku' command requires the '--app' parameter to target a given application, unless you run it from a application folder (clone of the Git repo containing your application).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this error occurs when the code is not pushed to heroku (git push heroku master) before running heroku ps.